# Why did my setInterval stop working?

Tags: javascript

Why did the 'setInterval' stopped working when I added the 'for' ?

```
<script>
    var x=0;
    setInterval(function() {counter()},1);
function counter()
{
     x++;
}
for(var start=0; start <= 100; start++)
    {
        alert("x is "+x+" and start is "+start);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Javascript isn't (in this case) multi threaded, your setInterval basically means "next time the main thread is not doing anything and the timeout has passed, have it execute my callback".

Your for loop blocks the main thread until it's done (and it won't exit until it has displayed the 101 alerts which are each waiting for user input) so your callback won't happen until the for loop has ended and main thread can go back to "not doing anything".

Comment: Might as well note that the problem isn't entirely the `for`, but rather the `alert` which is most often a synchronous action which halts script execution.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, thanks, I was a bit lacking in my description of the reason, added a comment about that in the answer.

Comment: +1, even though the DOM 0 `alert` has no specification and browsers may interpret it differently. For example, OP's interval will execute intermittently between the alerts on Firefox 15-18, while they will be completely synchronous on Chrome. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/7vDG8/)

Comment: @SamK. That would depend on what you're trying to do. Trying to measure the timing of the loop?

Comment: @SamK. Then I suggest you just do `var stime = new Date()` at the start of the loop and alert (or even better log to the console) `new Date() - stime` at good places to display the number of milliseconds since `stime`, that will not require any timeouts to run.